# Open eSignForms redeployment with existing database?

Tags: java, vaadin, tomcat8

I have been customizing [Open eSignForms](http://open.esignforms.com/) (**openesf**) for one my clients.

I have set up the **openesf** source code in Eclipse and also deployed it on one of our servers. As per their documentation, we have to copy all the contents of webcontent folder to the server (in tomcat/webapps) and run a linux shell script to set up the initial database.

Up to this point, the application worked fine. But when I made some changes to the code and copied the contents of web content folder again, the application won't start on server and keeps on complaining about missing class file **Library$Manager.class**. I'm replacing the previous webcontent files without running the db script this time, to avoid loss of data.

When I checked the classes folder the class file was there. I tried giving full permission to webapps directory but that didn't resolve the problem. However, when I dropped existing db and did the fresh db set the same code worked fine on server.

What am I missing here? Why does having a fresh database matter? What does that have to do with the missing class file?

Answer (score 0):

Our dev forums are here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openesignformsdev

A missing class file indicates you either built the JAR incorrectly, or perhaps had a compiler error of some sort so the build was not entirely successful.

When copy over the web contents, you need to be sure you don't overlay any customized .properties files under WEB-INF/classes, and if you store any .class files there, you'll need to be sure to update them as they take precedence over code in the JAR.

In particular, since you suggest a rebuilt DB solved it, perhaps you overwrote your prior connectionpools.properties file.  You definitely don't want to overwrite any properties files after you customize them as that can be catastrophic.